# Symfony Compile Error Failed opening required Proxies

Tags: symfony, sylius

I download a new sylius 1.5 project and i deploy it on a sharedhost server. In local all work very well both in dev and prod environnement. But online prod env don't work. Here is the exception in prod log

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException:

Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required 'var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__some-file.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php7:/usr/share/php') at vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php line 223
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem. thanks

When i laod page for the first time the page it work. But when i click on link or refresh the page i have a blank page with message

> this page is currently unable to handle this request

In  cPanel Configure PHP INI basic settings section i enable display_errors and when i refresh the page this error is displayed

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'phar:///home/ki327452/public_html/acme/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-shim/phpstan.phar/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/ki327452/public_html/acme/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-shim/bootstrap.php on line 8
```

I wait a few moment and when i refresh again it works.And that is a boucle in which i am.

Comment: did you try to clear cache and use cache:warmup?

Comment: I am on shared host  server , so i have not access to console. But i have done it by cron jobs. It's not working. I remove the cache  physically but the same problem

Comment: Maybe its a file permissions problem? (your application have no write permissions in "var/cache" etc ?)

Comment: I edit the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats maybe cause of proxies.

In config/doctrine.yaml :

```
doctrine:
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes:  true # <- change to true
    proxy_dir: '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
    proxy_namespace:      Proxies
```